# Setting up Fuseki 2 in Openshift

Tags: openshift, fuseki

I am trying to set up a Fuseki 2 instance in Openshift. I have tried using the Diy cartridge and running Fuseki 2 as a standalone server bound to the 8080 port, as required by Openshift.

This is the command employed to lauch the server:

```
./fuseki-server --port=8080
```

Unfortunately, there is a problem with the port binding and it does not work:

```
[2016-03-17 05:16:16] Server     INFO  Fuseki 2.3.1 2015-12-08T09:24:07+0000
[2016-03-17 05:16:16] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/56e9715489f5cfd91e00001a/app-root/runtime/repo/fuseki-2.3.1
[2016-03-17 05:16:16] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_BASE=/var/lib/openshift/56e9715489f5cfd91e00001a/app-root/runtime/repo/fuseki-2.3.1/run
[2016-03-17 05:16:16] Servlet    INFO  Initializing Shiro environment
[2016-03-17 05:16:16] Config     INFO  Shiro file: file:///var/lib/openshift/56e9715489f5cfd91e00001a/app-root/runtime/repo/fuseki-2.3.1/run/shiro.ini
[2016-03-17 05:16:17] Server     ERROR SPARQLServer: Failed to start server: Permiso denegado
java.net.SocketException: Permiso denegado
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.start(JettyFuseki.java:120)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.exec(FusekiCmd.java:359)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
    at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.innerMain(FusekiCmd.java:95)
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:60)
```

I have also tried listening only to the localhost interface `./fuseki-server --port=8080 --localhost`, but same result.

Comment: Did you try binding Fuseki to both `$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP` and `$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT`? You can get inspired e.g. in this [config file](https://github.com/semfact/openshift-fuseki/blob/master/conf/jetty.xml).

Comment: The `$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT` is 8080, so it's already set in my command above. About the host IP, this could be the culprit, but I don't find the way to change it in Fuseki2. That config file is for another version of Jetty and is not valid in Fuseki2. I have also tried to attach a Jetty 9 config file with the `$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP`, but then Fuseki shows an error about not finding Jetty classes.